# Удаляется файл в linux не смотря на то, что с ним работает программа

Tags: linux

Использую logrus, обнаружил такую особенность, что в линукс можно взять и удалить файлы куда пишутся логи.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на гифки видно, что идет запись, но тем не менее я спокойно удалил файл. В виндовс так не выходит, при удалении появляется сообщение, что файл занят другой программой, что нормально.

Файл создаю и устанавливаю в logrus так:

```golang
tmp, _ := os.OpenFile(filepath.Join(dir, "Log_"+time.Now().Format("15.04.05")), os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, os.ModeAppend)
logrus.SetOutput(tmp)
```

Comment: Норма — понятие относительное. Действительно, в юникс-системах можно удалить открытый файл. При этом место на диске, занимаемое этим файлом, будет освобождено только после его закрытия.

Comment: а нельзя как-то заблокировать удаление?

Comment: @АртемАртемыч, если кратко — нет (хотя всегда возможно внести изменения в ядро)... да и не особо понятно, зачем такое может кому-то понадобиться...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, `В Ext4 добавлена поддержка пустот в каталогах (не привязанных блоков). Обеспечена обработка флага "i" (immutable) для открытых файлов (запрет записи в ситуации, если флаг был установлен в момент, когда файл уже был открыт);` http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=51447

Comment: @Fat-Zer, получается, что пользователь (админ) может взять и удалить файлы куда пишет логи logrus и все, ничего не логируется. Эт что делать горутину которая периодически будет проверять существование файли и если его нет, создавать?

Comment: @donRumata, как описано, это не даст писать в файл в том числе процессу, который его уже открыл... это определённо не то, чего хочет OP... кроме того для установки флага нужен специальный мандат и ЕМНИП поддерживается этот атрибут не на всех ФС...

Comment: @АртемАртемыч, пользователь/админ  рассматривается, как человек, который знает, чего он хочет и к каким последствиям приведут его действия... если он знает, что какой-то файл логов ему в будущем не понадобится, не вижу причин, почему бы благородному пользователю его не удалить... Если всё же очень хочется, то можно, например, подсунуть `logrus`'у в `SetOutput` объект, который при каждой записи в лог будет переоткрывать файл... или проверять, что он существует... вместо банальной проверки можно повесится на событие `inotify` (в go для этого должен быть интерфейс)...

Comment: так еще получается что место на диске занято, а файла нет. логописец такой может сожрать всё пространство